# How to scroll map when drawing lines on Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps

When drawing a line on Bing Maps (such as drawing a walking route), how do you scroll the map when you get to the edge? The arrow keys don't work whilst in drawing mode. Using IE11 on Windows 8.1

Comment: How do you draw in the first place? This does not seem to be an option I have available.

Comment: You have to open "My places" first to get the drawing options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to move around the map while in drawing mode.

## Zooming

Move the mouse to the center of the screen, then scroll down to zoom out. Move the mouse to the point where you want to draw and scroll up to zoom in.

## Context menu

The second method is to right click near the edge of the screen, and choose `Center map at this location`. The map now moves and you can continue to draw.

Comment: Thanks for these two tips - they both work. A little fiddly and it would be nice if Bing worked liked Google Maps used to (when you could use it for personal maps) and auto-scrolled when you hovered near the edge of the map